# How to resume a file download in firebase Storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I need to download a big file using firebase storage, 
it is possible my user face network interruption through the download and i would like to be able to resume this download task.

```
 FileDownloadTask downloadTask = firebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(url).getFile(localFile);

    downloadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

        @Override
        public void onProgress(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Log.v(TAG, "progress" + taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred());;
            }
    });

    downloadTask.addOnFailureListener(e -> {
        CustomLogger.v(TAG, "downloadTask, on Failed: " + courseId);
        deleteFilesAfterError(courseId);
    });

    downloadTask.addOnPausedListener(taskSnapshot
            -> CustomLogger.v(TAG, "downloadTask, on paused: " + courseId));
```

the two last listener are never called. when i set up the complete listener:

```
downloadTask.addOnCompleteListener()
```

my app crashes.

even when i set up :

```
firebaseStorage.setMaxDownloadRetryTimeMillis(2000);
```

then switch off my network in the middle of a download, the downloadTask fail listener is not trigger. The task still seems to be "in progress" but there no data are downloaded. The documentation is poor on this feature. how am i supposed to implement it?

- the fail listener seems broken
- when i add a completeListener it crashes my app
- firebaseStorage.setMaxDownloadRetryTimeMillis does not seems to have
  any effect

any idea on how to tackle a resume feature for a file download?

Answer (score 0):

When you say you switch off your network in the middle of the download, how are you doing this?

The reason I ask is because if you are leaving the activity temporarily to turn off the network stream then ***your problem might be an activity lifecycle problem.***

If you leave the activity and do not handle this in the `onPause()`, `onStop()` and so on then you might experience this sort of behavior.

Other than that, your code looks similar to the docs (and my code that works fine), other than the fact that you didn't 'chain' your methods to add the listeners (shouldn't be a problem).

However, your code that you copied and pasted here is partially folded and does not show whether or not you are overiding the `onFailure(Exception e)` method, but I assume it is folded up in that arrow.

If you are still working on this, can you post the trace for any errors you're receiving on the crash?

Here is a block of code that works during network failure, just for a reference:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://your-bucket/");

storageReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(YourActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(YourActivity.this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

                }
            }
```

Comment: i m not working on it anymore, this code was happening in a service, so not link to any activity life cycle. I was switching off and on the network using the normal button given by the phone